# React hooks: change state in parent function inside onClick function inside child function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, react-hooks, use-state

Hello I am trying to save data from a modal (child function) inside the main (parent) function. The modal loads certain html depending on which button is clicked (all do the same thing).

```
export default function () {
    const [addModal, setAddModal] = useState("display-none")
    const closeModal = () => setAddModal("display-none")
    const openAddModal = () => setAddModal("display-block")
    const [addModalType, setAddModalType] = useState("")

    const [savedData1, setSavedData1] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data1")) || [])
    const [savedData2, setSavedData2] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data2")) || [])
    const [savedData3, setSavedData3] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data3")) || [])

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("data1", JSON.stringify(savedData1))
        localStorage.setItem("data2", JSON.stringify(savedData2))
        localStorage.setItem("data3", JSON.stringify(savedData3))
        console.log(savedData1)
    })

    function addPoolFunction(e) {
        if (e.target.id === "btn1") {
            setAddModalType(<AddData1 />)
        } else if (e.target.id === "btn2") {
            setAddModalType(< AddData2 />)
        } else if (e.target.id === "btn3") {
            setAddModalType(< AddData3 />)
        }
    openAddPool()
    }
    return (
        <Modal show={addModal} handleClose={closeModal}>
            {addModalType}
        </Modal>
        <div>{savedData1.id}</div>
        <div>{savedData2.id}</div>
        <div>{savedData3.id}</div>

    )

    function AddData1() {
        const [idInput, setIdInput] = useState("")

        function add1() {
            let newObj = {id:idInput}
            //here is the issue. adding this obj to the savedData array so it will load in the parent function html
            setSavedData1(oldArray => [...oldArray, newObj]) // this does not work
        }

        return (
            <input value={idInput} onChange={e => setIdInput(e.target.value)}></input>
            <button onClick={add1}>Add</button>
        )
    }

    // (same functions for AddData2 and AddData3 with some variations as to how data is collected)
}
```

The main issue is setting the saved data. when I press the add button the `useEffect` then logs and the array is empty. Ive tried even saving the data in localStorage instead of using the `setSavedData1` function I `console.log` the localStorage `data1` right after I set it in the add1 function and it seems to appear in the array but the `useEffect` logs right after it and it is always empty. I would really anyone help as I am super stuck on this and don't know what to do.

Comment: May you include a working codepen version or the repo for me to test this?

Comment: And I don't get how you can render something like ``<div/><div/>``, since you can only return one value (Here there are two)

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to add a dependency array as a second argument to your useEffect.
Thing is, if you don't specify such array, useEffect will run each and every render, resulting in setting data from your localStorage all over again.
Try something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("data1", JSON.stringify(savedData1))
    localStorage.setItem("data2", JSON.stringify(savedData2))
    localStorage.setItem("data3", JSON.stringify(savedData3))
    console.log(savedData1)
}, []);
```

And also read this for more info:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Turns out the issue was something not related to the code above. I have fixed the issue but one more issue remains when I refresh the data should remain as it should be saved in localStorage but for some reason its not saving